# How efficient is encodeURIComponent?

Tags: javascript, performance, encodeuricomponent

How efficient is the encodeURIComponent implementations in major browsers? Is it worth memoizing calls to encodeURIComponent?

Comment: How many are you making?

Comment: I believe it's as efficient as possible, iterating over the given string once and replacing only the characters that do not fit in URL. I don't think you can find anything more efficient. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like premature optimization.

Unless you've profiled your page and found that `encodeURIComponent` is taking too much time, you shouldn't worry about it.